# Store loopback User in mysql

Tags: loopbackjs

I want to reuse the loppback's User login and token logic for my app, and to store the info in mySql.

When I leave User's datasource as default (in memory db), it works fine. Explorer is there.

Now I just want to change the datasource for User, and I  edit model-config.json to use my db connector:

```
 ...
  "User": {
    "dataSource": "db"
  },
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "ACL": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
```

...

After I restart the server and play a bit around, it objects that some tables are not in the db:

```
{ Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'mydb.ACL' doesn't exist
```

Obviously there is no table structure to store users, acls and other stuff in mySql.

How do I get this scheme structure in my db?
Is there a script or command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it myself, it's pretty easy:

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Creating+database+tables+for+built-in+models

Leaving the question if somebody else needs it...